# How to stop repeating of variables of "setInterval" Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm a beginner at JS , Now am programming a javascript app

in the app there is a button when the user clicks on it, a door supposed to be opened for 10 seconds then close again

I used "set interval" to do this function by :

```
    var rVars = []
    rVars.push( {name:"door", val:1} ) // 1 for open , 0 for close

  _server.setRoomVariables(r, user, rVars)
  var params = {}
  params.user = user
  params.r = r
  
  myInterval = setInterval("TimeForClose", 20000, params)
```

This is the code responsible for closing the door after 10 seconds

```
function TimeForClose(params){

    var rVars = []
    rVars.push( {name:"door", val:0} )

  _server.setRoomVariables(params.r, params.user, rVars)}
```

And it was done successfully, but the problem was that I found the function "TimeForclose" repeats every 10 seconds , which makes when another user click on the button and door opens for him, the first one repeated function which still repeats will close the door for the second user too and both functions of each of them will be repeated , and so on .

So I read I have to use "clear interval" or timer to stop repeating but when I used it, it didn't stop the repeating so I think I used it Incorrectly

So what's the best way to stop repeating? ( I just want the function to occurs once when someone click on a button then it stops ) .

I hope you give me the correct syntax of the code

Comment: try setTimeout function instead of interval

Comment: @Sagar would you please write the code for me Depending on the above code?
I'm beginner with Javascript , thank you

Comment: Just replace setInterval by [setTimeout](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval).

Comment: @Alpeto added one answer

Comment: @Sagar thank you for helping but when I did as u said the door now doesn't close at all
So Can you tell me how to use clearInterval() ?

Comment: @Sagar that's the problem when I used SetTimeout :
Cannot convert [object Object] to java.lang.Long

Comment: Check which params are you receiving in function because funcion is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as u said u can use `clearInterval()` after closing of that door window, try that once

Comment: where shall I put it exactly?
in a new function or where?

Comment: use new function to call clearInterval(), here the new function has to call after closing of ur door window

Comment: I understand you But excuse me for my lack of experience, I am still a beginner

can you please write it depending on above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only execute once, you can use [setTimeout](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
change setIntervalm to setTimeout

```
 myInterval =  setTimeout("TimeForClose", 20000, params)
```

The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method.

If you need to repeat excution and stop based on some external event you can use [clearTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)